# Eclipse terminal trims characters after a certain point. Limit width size

Tags: windows, eclipse, cmd, terminal

eclipse terminal, for some reason, refuse to receive extra characters. My intuitive approach was `Windows-->preferences-->Terminal` but there's nothing there that indicates the width size limitation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

having same issue with windows10 and eclipse Oxygen.2

workaround for me is to open local terminal when eclipse is NOT maximized, hence eclipse can be maximized again and terminal still behave without characters 
trimmed

no need to switch to legacy console mode that also worked

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with Terminal and Teminal+ in Eclipse, under Windows 10. It seems to be a known Eclipse bug related to the new Windows 10 command prompt: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514287

The workaround in the comment fixed it for me, which is to use the legacy console in Windows 10, as explained here https://www.top-password.com/blog/windows-10-command-prompt-new-console-vs-legacy-console/

Answer (score 0):

> This worked for me, check Fixed width console, and maximum char width=150, save and restart eclipse

> once it working, then after u can reset it by uncheck, it will no impact

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Windows-->Preferences > Run/Debug > console > Limit console output > uncheck
and set Fixed width console

[image]

Comment: thanks; it's off :-(  I have exactly your screen with same values.

Comment: changing above values will change your console setting

Comment: @adhg as above answer works for you .. you can accept and up-vote the solution so other will be benefited

Comment: I think my answer was ambiguous. what I mean it that I have the exact settings that you show and still the problem occurs. I stll have limitation with respect to the width (80 chars) and I have exercised different settings. any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

The **layout** of a command-window cannot be readily set by command-line options.  You can make a **shortcut** to

```
\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

and in the shortcut's *properties*, you can edit the layout just as you would edit the layout directly on a command window.  The layout tab in the properties dialog lets you set the number of lines/columns in the *window* as well as the number of lines/columns for the *buffer*.  (The window can be much smaller than the buffer).

Here's a screenshot to illustrate the properties sheets

[image: screenshot showing shortcuts to cmd, modified]

Given a suitable shortcut, you can tell Eclipse where to find that, and execute it.